# swift - UINavigationController extension not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm going to be using similar properties on all of my navigation controllers in the different view controllers with the exception of some navigation items and obviously the titles.

I made an extension planning to be able to call it and have my defaults set; however, it doesn't do anything. The code does work when I simply place it in the actual class but not when I call the SetDefaults.

**Extensions**:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func setDefaults(titleText: String){
        let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        //Set title label
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: appDel.regularDefaultFont, size: 16)
        label.text = titleText
        label.kern(1.0)
        label.sizeToFit()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = label

        //Set white background tint color
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        //Set navigation bar bottom line
        let bottomBorderRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 1)
        let bottomBorderView = UIView(frame: bottomBorderRect)
        bottomBorderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 250, g: 250, b: 250)
        self.navigationBar.addSubview(bottomBorderView)
    }
}
```

Call to SetDefaults from class with a navigationcontroller:

```
self.navigationController.SetDefaults("Login")
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in your extension and see whether it's reached?

Comment: make sure you're actually calling `setDefaults` on the right navigation controller. If you use UISplitViewController the view controller's own navigation controller property might not be the one on screen

Comment: kabiroberai, I tried that and it does get there. @Luke I'm calling the setDefaults in the view controller that I just showed. Is this correct? Check out my comment to the response below to see the code I use to show the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your Storyboard you should select `Segue` type to `show`  while connecting one View Controller to the other 
or simply select your segue > in attributes inspector > storybook segue > kind > show ( e.g) push.
as shown in this image

[image]

It'll resolve the issue permanently :)

Comment: Faiz, I'm showing the view controller through code.                                    `let loginController = vcLogin()
        self.navigationController?.showViewController(loginController, sender: nil)` Also, I'm calling the set defaults in the vcLogin controller.. is that correct?

Comment: @Walker, Please check my new Answer & to do let me know if it works or perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

your code should be look like this.

```
let vcLogin = loginViewController(
            nibName: "loginViewController",
            bundle: nil)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vcLogin,
            animated: true )
```

Hopefully this works like a water flow...

Comment: @Walker, did you followed my code & is it working now on your side?
Please update me about your feedback